# Removed list left data on RBS volume

Tags: document-library, remote-blob-storage

We had an DB cluster failure lastly and somehow manage to get it working again. The problem is, that one of our content databases is RBS enabled and I found out that some of the data is missing there (I was uploading part of documents on January 18th and last modified files are from January 17th). Trying to access one of our libraries (which kept most of the data) was throwing and sharepoint error.

I decided to delete this library through PowerShell and that went smooth. But when I investigated the RBS volume, I found out that binary data which belonged to that library is still there. Do you have any clue how I could safely remove this data? Or maybe it's better to leave it as-is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RBS Garbage Collector should do this for you. This is expected behaviour with RBS.

Comment: Any ideas how long can it take?

Comment: Depends on the RBS store size; can take a while.